# How to tell if an acid disassociate completely or partially?

Tags: acid-base

what is the difference between

[image] and

[image]

how can I tell which one is the stronger acid, base on the 2 equations?

Comment: You need to know the dissociation constants of your acids to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, writing acetic acid as CH3COOH would be good start, Knowing common strong acids and types of weak ones as next step would be enough to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The equations don't tell you the complete story, just as by looking at an equation one cannot predict the boiling point of HCl, in the same way we cannot say how many HCl or acetic acid molecules are dissociating in water.  In easy words, if you had 0.1 moles of HCl in 1 L of water, all of them will dissociate in water, however if you have acetic acid, then only 1.3% acetic acid molecules will dissociate and the rest will remain in molecular form. It is a dynamic process. To see how this is calculated see
https://www.chemteam.info/AcidBase/Calc-percent-dissoc-of-weak-acid.html

We should use double arrows when we show the dissociation of acetic acid.